# Не запускается файл pyuic5.bat

Tags: python

Здравствуйте. Я новичок в Питоне, делаю первое оконное приложение. 
При запуске команды

```
D:\PythonMy\PyQT>"C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Library\bin\pyuic5.bat" -x 
 untitled.ui -o  untitled.py
```

Пишет:

> "C:/Program" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой
>   программой или пакетным файлом.

Объясните пожалуйста, что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: Немного не понятно что это `D:\PythonMy\PyQT>` ?

Comment: Это директория, где хранится файл untitled.ui. Я делала по видео: https://youtu.be/Dmo8eZG5I2w

Answer (score 1):

У меня такая-же проблема.
Это говорит, что программа(файл) "pyuic5.bat" не найден в каталоге "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Library\bin"
Я бы посоветовал посмотреть этот файл в самом каталоге, перейдя в него командой
"cd C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Library\bin" и там команда "dir"
Я вот, когда писал ответ, обнаружил этот файл там.
Возможно, что этот файл находится где-то в другом месте. Дело в том, что не все используют пакет Anaconda и, значит, он может находиться в другом каталоге.
Вообще, в файле "pyuic5.bat" всего одна строка.
"@D:/ProgramFiles/Anaconda3\python.exe -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9"
Можно самому создать этот файл и туда эту строку поместить. Только, если pithon находится в другом каталоге, исправить подстроку "D:/ProgramFiles/Anaconda3" на подстроку пути, где находится pithon.exe
Странно, что такой простой прием не сделан в настройках самого дизайнера. Или там надо поковыряться, чтобы это обнаружить.
И еще.
Вот есть видео
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mPVcdNRUfo
и
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUM1eGveKS0
Может, что полезное там найдете

Comment: Кстати, вот тут https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SrD4l2o-uk прямо в коде делается загрузка файла с расширением ui через функцию loadUi

Comment: Возможно, это наиболее правильное решение. Не надо постоянно конвертировать и потом править конвертированный в питон код.